# Display numbers as currency?

Tags: visualforce, html

I have these 3 fields that I'm calling in my visualforce component. They are all Currency(16, 2), but when I'm calling them in my component, they are being displayed as numbere 1111.00. is there a way to convert them to currency? i want 1,000.00.

```
                <table class="sub_section sectionHighlight"><tr>  
                        <td class="mysub_section_label " >a):</td>   <td class="sub_section_data" > {!c.a__c}</td> 
                        <td class="mysub_section_label " >b:</td>     <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.b__c}</td> 
                        <td class="mysub_section_label " >c:</td>     <td class="sub_section_data " > {!c.c__c}</td>                      
                </tr></table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any reason why not to use an outputfield ? Doing so will automatically render field specifics according to user locale settings.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!c.a__c}"/>
```

Alternativly you could use the outputtext + formatting option:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, 000,000.00}">
       <apex:param value="{!c.a__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Visualforce has a lot of usefull components, have a look at the Standard Component Reference in the [Visualforce Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_compref.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_compref.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Comment: I think i did it because that kept on giving me the field label which i didn't want.

Comment: I the html you posted in your question within visualforce components ? And the outputText element will not show a label.

Comment: If using multi-currency, don't forget to pass in the `currencyIsoCode` to your component. If using advanced currency management, things get harder - see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007kScAAI and http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Visualforce-unable-to-display-any-currency-field-if-advanced/td-p/136824

Answer (score 1):

I found that Samuel's example, given a value of 0, will render `000,000.00`.

I solved it using the `currency` operator from MessageFormat:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}">
  <apex:param value="{!c.a__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Keep in mind, though: this solution prepends a dollar ($) sign to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<apex:outputText label="NRR" value="{0,number}">
    {! Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} &nbsp;
    <apex:param value="{! Opportunity.NRR__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

This gives you the Currency (CurrencyIsoCode) as well as the value (in proper format) if it exists in the field value.